# The preloadedState argument passed to createStore has unexpected type of "Null". Expected argument to be an object with the following keys: "login"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Guys i am having trouble debugging the error i have recently got in my application, which is
"The preloadedState argument to createStore has unexpected type of Null.Expected argument to be an object with the fillowing keys: "login""

Here is a reducer file code snippet which export combinedReducers

```
import {Map, fromJS} from 'immutable';
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';

import { login } from '../modules/login/LoginReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  login
});
```

======================================

## AND THE Login Reducer code snippet looks like

```
import {
  AUTH_USER,
  SET_ADMIN_PRIVILEGES,
  AUTH_ERROR
} from './login.types';

const INITIAL_STATE = { errors: null, authenticated: false, admin_privileges: false };

export const login =  (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
 switch(action.type) {
     case AUTH_USER:
            return { ...state, errors: null, authenticated: true };
        case SET_ADMIN_PRIVILEGES:
            return { ...state, admin_privileges: true };
         case AUTH_ERROR:
            return { ...state, errors: action.errors };
          default:
            return state;
 }

};
```

==============================

## AND THE STORE

```
import {applyMiddleware, createStore, compose} from 'redux';
import * as reduxLoop from 'redux-loop';

import middleware from './middleware';
import reducer from './reducer';

const enhancer = compose(
  applyMiddleware(...middleware),
  reduxLoop.install()
);

// create the store
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  null,
  enhancer
);

export default store;
```

========================
Please help guys..

Comment: If you don't want a preloaded state, you can just pass the `enhancer` as the second argument (redux will coalesce it)

Answer (score 7):

You can just pass and empty object.

```
const initialState = {}    
const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    initial_state,
    enhancer
);
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with the question asked

Comment: actually the answer was exactly what I was looking for when searching for the same error